# C# pass anonymous parameter?

Tags: c#

Sorry for title, I cant find the correct one. I have more than one method that returns the same result.

returning type

```
public class JsonTreeView
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string @checked { get; set; }
    public string attributes { get; set; }
    public List<JsonTreeView> children { get; set; }
}
```

first method

```
List<JsonTreeView> FromReportTree(List<ReportTree> list)
{
}
```

second method

```
List<JsonTreeView> FromLocationTree(List<LocationTree> list)
{
}
```

and anothers... properties of Tree models are different. for example :

```
LocationTree (id, name, parent, text)
ReportTree (sno, name, parent, desc)
```

Is it possible to write one method for all these tree models? Any suggestion or starting point?

Thanks...

Comment: Not sure about the correctness of the technique but you could have a base class that all the 'tree' classes inherit from and then you could pass a list of the base class. Doesn't feel 'right' but it should work.

Comment: TreeModels are represented DB tables. So if I do your suggestion, I should create additional DTO models, and cast them again to DB table models...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you make a private method that does the grunt work, and keep the overloaded methods for the different types. Call the private method from the other methods, with a function that creates a `JsonTreeView` object from the specific objects of that method:

```
private List<JsonTreeView> FromReportTree<T>(List<T> list, Func<T, JsonTreeView> convert) {
  // loop through the list and call convert to create items
  List<JsonTreeView> result = new List<JsonTreeView>();
  foreach (T item in list) {
    result.Add(convert(item));
  }
  return result;
}

List<JsonTreeView> FromReportTree(List<ReportTree> list) {
  return FromReportTree(list, t => new JsonTreeView(t.id, t.text, ... ));
}

List<JsonTreeView> FromReportTree(List<LocationTree> list) {
  return FromReportTree(list, t => new JsonTreeView(t.sno, t.desc, ... ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what happens in those methods. You say that the various Tree models have different properties; does the logic in the method need any of the non-common properties? If the logic in each of those methods is the same, you can do this:

```
List<JsonTreeView> FromReportTree<T>(List<T> list) where T : BaseTree
{
    //some logic
}
```

assuming you have a `BaseTree` model of some kind, otherwise `T : class` or just leave that off (not recommended).

If the logic differs, you can still do it like that by doing a check `if (list is LocationTree)` and using that to do the logic specific to `LocationTree`, but that can get messy.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing but I think I understand. You want a single FromReportTree function.

For that, you'd most likely want ReportTree and LocationTree to have a common base class. Like:

```
public abstract class ReportLocationTree {
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class ReportTree : ReportLocationTree {
    public string moreStuff { get; set; }
}

public class LocationTree : ReportLocationTree {
    public string evenMoreStuff { get; set; }
}

List<JsonTreeView> FromReportTree(List<ReportLocationTree> list)
{
    list.Select(t => new JsonTreeView { id = t.id }).ToList();
}
```

I wasn't sure how you were serailizing, so I Didn't include it in my code, but it's bad form to follow a different naming convention on your properties just because they're being serailized.

JSON.Net makes it pretty easy on you: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationAttributes.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you make all your Trees to implement an interface, you can.

```
interface iMyTree
{
    int MyTreeID {get; set;}
    string MyTreePame {get; set;}
    object MyTreeParent {get; set;}
    string MyTreeText  {get; set;}
}


class AnyTree : iMyTree
{
     //any properties

     //implements iMyTree
}
```

And that method:

```
List<JsonTreeView> FromMyTree(List<iMyTree> list)
{
    //all trees that implement iMyTree will have the same methods, any kind of tree implementing iMyTree can be used.
}
```